# QGIS 2.18.9: buffers too large in WGS84/UTM zone 34S

Tags: qgis

my original vector layer was saved in WGS84. In order to be able to calculate distances in meters I have saved the layer in WGS84/34S. I thought that the unit of measurement would be meters now. But when I create 50 meter buffers around buildings they come out way too large. When measuring distances they are given in milimeters instead of meters.

Which steps should be taken in order to get to a unit of measurement of meters?

Comment: Did you save to a new filename? And what extent is reported in the new layer's properties -> metadata tab?

Comment: I saved the original vector layer to a new shapefile with a different filename. Under layer properties-->CRS is says "Selected CRS (EPSG:32734, WGS84/UTM zone 34S)". The vector layer containing the buffers was also saved to a new shapefile with a new filename. In the layers properties it again says under CRS "WGS84/UTM zone 34S". Under metadata is says: "Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 0.408591,-54.0456 : xMax,yMax 40.5074,-13.997
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=34 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

Comment: The extent looks more like degrees. Has the "original" layer the same extent?

Comment: In the shapefile used to construct the buffer shapefile is says: "Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 20.4053,-34.0581 : xMax,yMax 20.5074,-33.9953
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=34 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

Comment: If that should cover the town Swellendam, the extent is in degrees, but the CRS is wrongly set to UTM 34S. You have to switch that back to EPSG:4326, then start from the beginning.